# update record via omniscript using integration procedure?

Tags: omnistudio, omniscript, data-raptor

I'm very new to OmniStudio and getting confused when trying to create an Integration Procedure in an OmniScript to update a record.

So, I have a FlexCard with an Action button that launches an OmniScript (via Flyout). I set attributes on the action to pass ContextId and AppId, I can see those are set correctly via Action Debugger. Next, on my OmniScript, I have a Step in which a radio button is selected. I want to then update the corresponding app record (that matches the AppId I passed from the flex card) with this value.

So what now? Do I need a SetValues in my OS before the step to set that AppId in the OS or does it pass on its own? Do I need to build a DRPostAction? Do I use an IPAction and use the Remote Options section to set the AppId and value from the radio selection?

How do I configure the IP? It would probable need a DRPost or do I also need a Set Values? In the DRPost do I utilize the Send/response Transformations section?

Sorry for all the questions this is just very confusing to me, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the strength of OmniStudio and its related components is that there are many different ways to do the same thing.
I am going to answer your questions in order.

1. Do I need a SetValues in my OS before the step to set that AppId in the OS or
   does it pass on its own?
   *You are saying that you are passing ContextId and AppId from the flyout. If that is the case then the root of your data json in the OS should have AppId and
   ContextId defined by the values that you are setting.*
2. Do I need to build a DRPostAction?
   *If your goal is to create a new record or update an existing record using only
   OmniStudio you will need to use a DR Post Action (Its also known as a Data
   Raptor Load) or an Integration Procedure that has a Data Raptor Load in it.*
3. Do I use an IPAction and use the Remote Options section to set the AppId and
   value from the radio selection?
   *You can use an Integration procedure here but you don't necessarily need to.
   You can always just use a DR Post Action (DR Load)*
4. How do I configure the IP?
   *There are a ton of ways to configure an IP. This question is too broad to
   really give a good response to without knowing more about your setup. However since you don't NEED an IP I would not go that route since you are still new.*
5. It would probable need a DRPost or do I also need a Set Values?
   *IF you were using an IP you would need DRPost but again I would not recommend
   for you to use an IP. You don't necessarily need a set values here.*
6. In the DRPost do I utilize the Send/response Transformations section?
   *I presume you are asking if you use the Send/response transformations within the IP for the DRPost action. I would not use an IP here. Having said that the send/response is primarily meant to change the name of the JSON node you are sending in or receiving (it can be more nuanced but this is the gist).*

Ultimately I would recommend that instead of asking what to do you should try to build it out and if you are running into implementation issues with specific issues ask those questions. I feel like most of these questions are too vague to give good meaningful answers.